# Activity Creator

Tags: android, shell, batch-file

What is the Activity Creator in Android?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`activityCreator` is a batch file and shell script used to create Android projects. That has long since been replaced by the `android create project`.

Answer (score 4):

Activity Creator was previously used to create new android projects. It was replaced by Create New Project. You may refer to given link:

http://eagle.phys.utk.edu/guidry/android/creatingAndroidProject.html

Comment: Sudipta for Android, i really apprewciate your answere Aditya1510

Answer (score 1):

The Activity Creator was a program used to create new projects in the andriod sdk. Now it is replaced by android create program
 http://developer.android.com/guide/tutorials/hello-world.html

Answer (score 1):

An ActivityCreator is the first step towards the creation of a new Android project. It is made up of a shell script that will be used to create new file system structure necessary for writing codes within the Android IDE.